# How do I check if raw_input == something in python?

Tags: python

This is what I wrote, could you please see what is wrong with my code. 
I am just a beginner at **Python**.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

input=int(raw_input("Write exit here: "))

if input==exit:
    print "Exiting!"
else:
    print "Not exiting!"
```

Comment: you need to read documentation first, I think.

Comment: Using names of built-ins like `input` is bad practice.

Answer (score 7):

You want to test equality for the string `"exit"`, so don't convert it to an `int`

```
text = raw_input("Write exit here: ")

if text == "exit":
    print "Exiting!"
else:
    print "Not exiting!"
```

`input==exit` compares `input` with the function `exit` which may have confused you.
If you tried `input == Exit` it wouldn't have even run.

Comment: You are doing `int(raw_input)`, you only need `raw_input`

Comment: +1, but he also needs to compare it to the string `"exit"` rather than the function `exit` (which you fixed in your code, but didn't mention).

Comment: Actually, I know I'm the one who called it a function, but… exit is actually not a function, it's a `Quitter`. But it's still a callable, and you can still legally compare it to a string or int (and always get False), so your answer is not at all misleading (and I think trying to be rigorous here would just confuse the OP); I'm just being nitpicky here.

Comment: @abarnert technically `itertools.chain` is not a function either so I don't think it's worth going into that

Answer (score 2):

Python is a scripting language - it is very easy to run python interactively (just type `python`) or run a debugger such as idle, eric, komodo (and etc...) and play with it. Here I tried some combinations to see what works and what doesn't:

```
>>> raw_input("write exit here: ")
write exit here: exit
'exit'
>>> my_input = raw_input("write exit here: ")
write exit here: exit
>>> my_input
'exit'
>>> my_input = int(raw_input("wite exit here: "))
wite exit here: exit

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    my_input = int(raw_input("wite exit here: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'exit'

>>> my_input == exit
False
>>> type(exit)
<class 'site.Quitter'>
>>> my_input == "exit"
True
```

But don't take my word for it.... open the interpreter and experiment with small parts of your problem and you'' have it working in no time.

Comment: I wish I could +5 this tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using the ternary operator.  It is useful to learn this and other Python constructs and idioms that reduce code complexity.  It is also not necessary to assign a name to the input unless it helps to explain the code.

```
print "Exiting!" if raw_input("Write exit here: ") == "exit" else "Not exiting!"
```

Comment: You can get the exact same advantage without the ternary operator: `if raw_input("Write exit here: ") == "exit":`.

Comment: True indeed.  Missed that.